# google api machine learning can I use an API KEY?

Tags: machine-learning, google-api

For learning purposes, I'm trying to use the Machine learning (ml) API.

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models/list

I'm not able to identify if this request can be done with an API KEY instead of OAUTH.

I'm using npm package `googleapis` with this;

```
ml.projects.models.list({
    key: GCLOUD_API,
    parent: "projects/"+GCLOUD_PROJECT
  }
```

But always receives this error:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

I've tried replacing `key` with `auth` or `token`. Nothing work.

How can I know if is possible or not to use an api key?

I tried also with curl

```
'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-123456/models?token=my_super_sekret_key'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I had the same doubt.

Here are GCP Services that support API Keys:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys and ML API is not included.

You should obtain the access token using OAuth2, so URL POST request will be:

https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/your_project/models?access_token=your_access_token

Works great for me. Same to do predictions.

Comment: how you obtained access token