# how to use google AI platform online predictions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

i created a custom tensorflow model and deployed to google cloud AI platform 
however, when i sent a post request to online prediction api (https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/models/my-model/versions/my-version:predict). i got back **401 Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token** my understand that by deploying model is its API already available online, so is there away to make API public? if not how i can make api authentication through bearer token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google api machine learning can I use an API KEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087267/google-api-machine-learning-can-i-use-an-api-key)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the auth token using gcloud:

```
access_token=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
```

and then embed it into the header:

```
curl --silent \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"  \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
```

etc.

Comment: This is for local development, using your local access token. But what about deploying an app, e.g. a website that makes requests to the API?

Comment: In that case, you would use service accounts (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-python)

Comment: @Anakhand did you figure it out?

Comment: @apeniche I got some advice on [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66584234/6117426), perhaps it might be useful to you too.

Comment: Thanks @Anakhand, I asked because this wasn't clear for me (how to do it with a pure http/rest approach -no python library-) so I had to research a bit more to figure it out. I was able to accomplish it, here are the docs in case this is useful for anyone: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest